# Doxygen does not generate except the empty mainpage

Tags: doxygen

I have a problem with `Doxygen GUI`
I am currently using version of the `Doxygen 1.8.19`
I selected project path and directory for the scan source code correctly,
And activated `EXTRACT_ALL` to `ENABLE`.

The output I see:

[image]

I have .cpp and .c codes together. But main is cpp so I added detail file in main.cpp as a:

```
/**
  * @file           : main.cpp
  * @brief          : Main program body
```

When I Run doxygen button, I have just seen,

Empty Main page and I cant see another Tab.

How can I solve this problem?

My source code:

In main.cpp file:

```
/**
*@mainpage  MyPROJECT
*
*
*
*/

/**
   *@file         main.cpp
   *@brief        This is the main source code of the project.
*/....
```

In main.h file:

```
/**
*@mainpage  MYPROJECT
*
*
*
*/


    /**
       *@file         main.h
       *@brief        This is the main source code of the project.
    */
    ...
```

Comment: You can only have one `\mainpage` in your project. Only the comment from the comment block with the `\mainpage` will land on the main page

Comment: I removed /mainpage from main.h file but it didnt solve my problem

Comment: Probably some misunderstanding about what lands where. The documentation in the comment block with the `\mainpage` will land on the "Main Page". The documentation in the comment blocks with the `@file` will land on the pages describing trhe mentioned file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
For those who get the same error as me:

Before the `"Run doxygen"` save the Doxygen file to where `main.cpp` file to copy there. 
For example your `main.cpp` file in the Src/main.cpp than you have to copy "Doxygen.txt" file to Src/main.cpp.

And it works !

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are writing. Do you mean that you have to copy the doxygen configuration file? Can you show some resulting output?

Comment: My file system seperate some function and library. Inc file and Src file have lots of .c and .h file. When I generate the Doxygen.txt file to project directory I saw as I have problem . But when I generate Doxygen.txt file in Src folder A mean, main.cpp in the Src file so it works. I dont understand why, I think doxygen cannot see all files. Is there any configuration for this ?

Comment: I don't know which settings you aleady used / tried, but probably `INPUT` and `RECURSIVE` could be of some use.

Comment: RECURSIVE->ENABLE and I added Inc and Src folder to Input path

Comment: I added netw topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403371/doxygen-file-system

Answer (score 0):

Getting text on the Main Page is not triggered by the name of the file but can be accomplished with

- the `@mainpage` command (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdmainpage)
- creating a markdown file (say my_main.md) and use the configure doxygen with `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE=my_main.md` (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_use_mdfile_as_mainpage)

Small note:
When the file documentation is in the same file as the file itself the name of the file with the `@file` command is not necessary  (and `@file` can actually be omitted. The `:` is also not OK.

Comment: I added @mainpage and did USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE congifuration like you and remove ":" but It didnt work again I see empty Doxygen file :(

Comment: Please show in your question by means of an edit (and properly shown as edit to the original question) what you tried. make a small complete example out of it that we can reproduce.

Comment: I added part of code. I can not see any files TAB and I can not see any function biref although I have lots of function.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen use `INPUT` option in Doxyfile to configure source file location, the previous way of moving Doxyfile is not elegant. See https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_input as reference.

> If this tag is empty the current directory is searched.

If your `main.cpp` is in `src` directory, in Doxyfile use:

```
INPUT                  = src
```

Or else you have more directories containing source files, like `include`, `tools` etc., try use:

```
INPUT                  = src include tools utility tests
```

In some cases you just need to document some files, for example you can use:

```
INPUT                  = src/Config/configParser.cpp
```

You can also use `INPUT_FILTER` and `FILTER_PATTERNS` to search in directories and match multiple files, refer to https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_filter_patterns

Also, to ensure that doxygen search for subdirectories of your INPUT directories, use:

```
RECURSIVE              = YES
```