# Doxygen Seperate Inc/ and Src/ file problem

Tags: doxygen, doxygen-wizard

My project folder name is MyDoxy
I have  separate file system that is `MyDoxy/Src/` and `MyDoxy/Inc/` folder and they have some .c and .h files.
`main.cpp` in the `Src/` folder.

When I generate the `Doxygen.txt` file in the MyDoxy file path. It doesn't generate files and file I talked about in the this post: [Doxygen does not generate except the empty mainpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384151/doxygen-does-not-generate-except-the-empty-mainpage/62387589?noredirect=1#comment110364982_62387589)
But when I create in the MyDoxy/Src/ path. It works for main.cpp and .c file but it didn't work for .h file for example `main.h` file.

```
        RECURSIVE              = YES
    INPUT                  = MyDoxy/Src
                          = MyDoxy/Inc
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a comment.

The syntax for `INPUT` is wrong, you will have had a warning about this when running doxygen.

The `INPUT` should either be:

```
    INPUT                  = MyDoxy/Src MyDoxy/Inc
```

or

```
    INPUT                  = MyDoxy/Src \
                             MyDoxy/Inc
```

or

```
    INPUT                  = MyDoxy/Src
    INPUT                 += MyDoxy/Inc
```

In which directory did you run doxygen?

Comment: I didnt any change on the Doxygen files I am usind Doxygen Wizard and I added on that Program. But when I look the output doxygen.txt second one using

Comment: From other posts I think you are running doxygen 1.8.19 (most likely self compiled as it is the master version). start on the directory in a terminal window where the `doxygen.txt` is the command `doxygen doxygen.txt` and have a look at the warnings you get. Further run also `doxygen -x doxygen.txt` to see what you actually changed compared to the default doxygen settings and report this in the question.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. I generate with command in terminal with doxygen Doxyfile but in the DoxyWizard and click Run Doxygen I have lots of error. What caused this?

Comment: I think Doxywizard does not work how can I solve this

Comment: I think that the doxywizard is working but on a different directory than you think it is. Without knowing the errors it is impossible to tell what the problem is you encounter.

Comment: But how can I get error? I have two doxygen folder in home source: doxygen and doxygen-1.8.18 . But I see version of doxygen 1.8.19

Comment: I don't know who installed your system, but there must have been a reason for having doxygen and dooxygen-1.8.18. In a terminal  window when giving `doxygen -v` you can see which version of doxygen you are exactly using. Regarding the error you mentioned: "click Run Doxygen I have lots of error" so you see the errors, I think you can cut and paste them or use the "Save Log"